# How to log periodically a variable on background

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I would like to log a variable (local scope) every second in python 3.5.

The call should be asyncronous (means the main thread should keep running).

I have tried the following code :

```
def functionX(self):
    #do stuff
            class BackgroundTimer(Thread):

                    def run(self):
                         while True:
                             print("sum_data ", sum)
                             sleep(60)


                    timer = BackgroundTimer()
                    timer.start()

    #keep doing stuff
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried the following code :" There's no code there...

Comment: Had to reboot :) happens read edits you will see that I just added the "following code"